# Apply horizontal scroll to div containing a Grid for all screen resolution

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have divided screen layout into two sections each of col-lg-6. I have placed a grid having 6 columns inside col-lg-6. For desktop size above 1280px width  the Grid  fits properly into col-lg-6. But below 1280px screen size the Grid exceeds out of col-6 size.

I want to apply horizontal scroll to Grid or Grid container div when the screen size reduces below 1280px.(lets consider the minimum mobile screen size up to 300px).

I have tried different solutions as follows:

1. Apply white-space=normal for td tag of Grid table
2. Apply table-responsive class at Grid container div
3. Apply table-responsive-lg table-responsive-md table-responsive-sm at Grid level
4. Solution provided at link https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/zaazhp2d/.
5. Applying scroll to Grid container div using media query for screen width below 1280px.

   ```
    <div class="row col-lg-12">
     <div class="col-lg-6">some asp.net controls </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="row col-lg-12">
            some asp.net controls 
        </div>
        <div class="row col-lg-12">
            <div class="container">
                <telerik:RadGrid ID="rad1" runat="server" class="table- 
                responsive-sm table-responsive-md table-responsive-lg">
               <%--Grid Template columns --%>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   ```

But none of this worked. I am unable to understand what CSS style I am missing. I have used table-responsive class in some pages and it worked for me, but here it is not. I have recently started using bootstrap 4 for responsive designs.

Comment: where is the snippet? please provide snippet so we can help you in your case

Comment: updated the already provided mark up for better understanding.The issue arises in responsive mode .Since the grid contains 6 columns and record data even after removing no-wrap exceeds out of the container width

Comment: Snippet means that code shows me problem in live preview mode

Answer (score 0):

Try applying below css for horizontal scroll.

```
.your-grid-container{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: i tried it .still issue exists in responsive mode for smaller devices